# magento 2 We found conflicting component dependencies

Tags: magento

Magento is giving me this error while Readiness Check during installing an extension.

```
Command "update" failed: Loading composer repositories with package information


[Composer\Downloader\TransportException] 
The 'https://repo.magento.com/packages.json' URL required authentication. 
You must be using the interactive console to authenticate 


update [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--lock] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-autoloader] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [--no-suggest] [--with-dependencies] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--apcu-autoloader] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--prefer-stable] [--prefer-lowest] [-i|--interactive] [--root-reqs] [--] [<packages>]...
```